# Call a visiblox chart that created with c# code in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

Is there a way to call a Visiblox `Chart` that created with C# code in WPF?

Let's say that i have created a chart like :

```
private Chart CreateNewChart(int num_chart, string chartName)
{
    Chart newChart = new Chart();
    newChart.Name = "Chart_"+num_chart;
    newChart.Title = chartName;
    newChart.Width = 600;
    newChart.Height = 120;
    newChart.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    newChart.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    newChart.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    newChart.Margin = new Thickness(0, (num_chart * 110), 0, 0);
    BehaviourManager behaviour = new BehaviourManager();
    behaviour.AllowMultipleEnabled = true;
    TrackballBehaviour track = new TrackballBehaviour();
    ZoomBehaviour zoom = new ZoomBehaviour();
    behaviour.Behaviours.Add(track);
    behaviour.Behaviours.Add(zoom);
    newChart.Behaviour = behaviour;
    return newChart;
}
```

And when I import some date from a CSV file, I want to add more data from another CSV file. Is there a way to call this created `Chart` with each name, or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="ThingNamespace.MainWindow"
     xmlns:ctest="clr-namespace:ThingNamespace"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:charts="clr-namespace:Visiblox.Charts;assembly=Visiblox.Charts"
     Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600" x:Name="TheWindow">

     <charts:Chart x:Name="myChart" />
</window>
```

Then in your codebehind 'myChart' will be available and you can do all the setup and configuration of the chart in your MainWindow methods:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myChart.Title = chartTitle;
    myChart.Width = 600;
    myChart.Height = 120;
    ...
}
```

etc. 'myChart' will be scoped to your MainWindow class, so you can make whatever helper methods you need to setup you chart.

However, doing everything in code behind isn't the WPF way, the WPF way would be to setup most or all of it in XAML. You can see the examples on their website in how to control the charts through XAML. http://www.visiblox.com/examples/LineChart

Comment: My exercise is to create a programm that every time i push a button i dynamically create a visiblox chat with tow buttons  on named import and one named more... I;m at the spot that i can dynamically with c# generate as many as i want line charts and put them in a grid with their buttons.. When i press import everything is ok but when i want to add some more lines in the chart from another file, i want to know how can i call from a specific button with a name that is the same name of te chart to instantiate again the chart and add more lines... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your asking correctly, you wouldn't reference the `Chart` object by it's `Name` property - that is really only if you have it added on the UI. Instead, you would store the object somewhere (global variable, collection of `Chart` objects, etc) and then call the objects directly from that store.

Comment: No i mean : Create a chart from csv file's data with code and put it in a grid. Then with a button parse some data from another csv file and dynamically import them to the previous chart... If it was in xaml then it would be easy with something like binding but now it is all created from scratch with c# code...